# Rails Scope Using Arel With Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning about scopes using arel in place of the find_by_sql.  I understand the basics, but am having trouble with the following.  I am in the Instructor model.

```
instructor has_many taught_classes

taught_classes has_many past_enrollements

past_enrollments belongs_to student
```

Playing with this in the console:

```
Instructor.includes(taught_classes: :past_enrollments)
```

This works - no errors.  I think it is written this way, because Instructor has_many taught_classes, which has_many past_enrollments.  But, when I try to add in Students, it does not see the students model/table.

```
Instructor.includes(taught_classes: {past_enrollments: :student})
```

The above works, in that it does not error out, but does not include the students model when I can view the sql displayed in the console. Would that be because Instructors is not directly linked to students?  How do I add students into this keeping in mind that past_enrollments belongs_to students?

What I want to do is something like this:

```
Instructor.includes(taught_classes: {past_enrollments: :student}).where("students.id = 1234").references(:students)
```

So, I need the student model/table included in the scope.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Untested, off the top of my head ponderance: does students need to be pluralized in your hash query construction? I.e., `{ past_enrollments: :students }`.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not it, "I tried".  I think it has to do with the direction of the associations in the line of the scope.  Instructor has many taught_classes, which has many past_enrollments, but students links the other way.  Student has many past_enrollments.  Weird I cannot figure out to code this so it sees students to past_enrollments.